# Adding a Threaded Comment functionality in my Django blog using FETCH API

Tags: javascript, django, fetch-api

I have a Django blog and I am trying to implement a threaded comment functionality using FETCH API to avoid a page refresh each time a comment is submitted. Also, I intend to limit the number of comments shown first to just 10 with a "load more comments" button at the bottom that when clicked would reveal the next 10 comments, and so on until there is no more comment to be shown at which point the "load more comments" button disappears.

You see, I successfully implemented this feature with FETCH API for only single parent comments. But I am trying to take my blog further by adding a threaded comment, or rather, to make it possible for parent comments to have child comments. However, I can't seem to successfully implement the above functionalities asynchronously. Only after reloading the page do the parent comments and child comments show on the page, but I want the comments to show immediately after hitting the comment submit button. I believe the problem is with my JavaScript but I am going to show all parts of my code that are related to the comments in case there is something that I'm missing.

Below is the relevant parts of my code.

In my models.py I have -

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()

    # Define get_depth before the ForeignKey field
    def get_depth(self):
            depth = 0
            parent = self.parent_comment
            while parent is not None:
                depth += 1
                parent = parent.parent_comment
            return depth

    '''null=True, blank=True; This is important because not all comments will have a parent comment 
    root-level comments)'''
    parent_comment = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='replies',
                                       on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}'s comment"

    def get_replies(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(post=self.post, parent_comment=self).order_by('date_posted')

    def snippet(self):
        return self.comment[:100] + '...'
```

My urls.py has -

```
path('comment_submit/<str:slug>/', views.comment_submit, name='comment_submit'),
    path('comments/<str:slug>/', views.get_comments, name='get_comments'),
    path('load_more_comments/<slug:slug>/<int:offset>/', views.load_more_comments, name='load_more_comments'),
```

My views.py has -

```
def detail(request, slug):
    user_authenticated = request.user.is_authenticated
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

    # Load related articles
    category = post.category
    related_articles = Post.objects.filter(category=category).exclude(id=post.id).order_by('-date')[:5]
    show_all = related_articles.count() >= 5

    # Load root-level comments and their associated replies
    root_comments = post.comments.filter(parent_comment__isnull=True).order_by('-date_posted')
    threaded_comments = []

    for root_comment in root_comments:
        comment_data = {
            'comment': root_comment,
            'replies': post.comments.filter(parent_comment=root_comment).order_by('date_posted'),
        }
        threaded_comments.append(comment_data)

    batch_size = 10
    total_comments = root_comments.count()
    show_load_more = total_comments > batch_size

    context = {
        'user_authenticated': user_authenticated,
        'post': post,
        'related_articles': related_articles,
        'show_all': show_all,
        'threaded_comments': threaded_comments,
        'show_load_more': show_load_more,
        'batch_size': batch_size,
        'total_comments': total_comments,
        'comments': threaded_comments
    }

    return render(request, 'article/read.html', context=context)

def load_more_comments(request, slug, offset):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    batch_size = 10
    comments = post.comments.filter(parent_comment__isnull=True).order_by('-date_posted')[offset:offset + batch_size]

    serialized_comments = []  # Serialize comments into a list
    for comment in comments:
        serialized_comments.append({
            'user': comment.user.username,
            'date_posted': comment.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),  # Format date as string
            'comment': comment.comment,
        })

    return JsonResponse(serialized_comments, safe=False)

@require_POST
@login_required
def comment_submit(request, slug):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the comment data from the request and save it to the database
        comment_text = request.POST.get('comment')
        # Assuming you have already authenticated the user
        user = request.user
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        comment = Comment.objects.create(post=post, user=user, comment=comment_text)
        comment_data = {
            'user': comment.user.username,
            'date_posted': comment.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
            'comment': comment.comment,
        }
        print("Comment data before sending JSON response:", comment_data)
        return JsonResponse(comment_data)
    return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request method'})

# This view is to fetch the comment after a page reload


def get_comments(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)

    comment_list = []
    for comment in comments:
        comment_data = {
            'user': comment.user.username,
            'date_posted': comment.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
            'comment': comment.comment,
        }
        comment_list.append(comment_data)

        # Debugging statements to inspect the data being sent
        #print("comment_list:", comment_list)

    return JsonResponse(comment_list, safe=False)
```

The relevant part of my detail html is -

```
<div id="comment-container" class="comment-container" style="display: none;">
                      <form id="comment-form" method="post" action="{% url 'article:comment_submit' post.slug %}" data-slug="{{ post.slug }}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <textarea id="comment-textarea"
                                  style="font-size: 16px; color: #333; background-color: #f2f2f2; border: 1px solid #ccc; 
                                  border-radius: 4px; padding: 8px; outline: none; text-align: left;" name="comment" rows="4" cols="50">
                        </textarea>
                        <button id="submit-comment" style="display: block;" type="submit">Submit</button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
    
                  <div id="comments-section">
                    {% for comment_data in threaded_comments %}
                      <div class="comment {% if comment.get_depth > batch_size %}hidden{% endif %}">
                        <div class="comment-header">
                          <h3>{{ comment_data.comment.user }}</h3>
                          <span class="timestamp">{{ comment_data.comment.date_posted }}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment-body">
                          <p>{{ comment_data.comment.comment }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment-footer">
                          <button class="comment-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-comment"></i>Reply</button>
                          <button class="like-button"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i>Like</button>
                          <button class="like-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>Delete</button>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        {% with replies=comment_data.comment.get_replies %}
                        {% if replies %}
                        <div class="child-comments">
                          {% for reply in replies %}
                          <div class="comment">
                            <div class="comment-header">
                              <h3>{{ reply.user }}</h3>
                              <span class="timestamp">{{ reply.date_posted }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment-body">
                              <p>Reply to User 1
                                {{ reply.comment }}
                            </p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="comment-footer">
                            <button class="comment-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-comment"></i>Reply</button>
                            <button class="like-button"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i>Like</button>
                            <button class="like-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>delete</button>
                          </div>
                          <hr>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endwith %}
                  </div>
                  {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                  
                  
                  {% if show_load_more %}
                    <!-- Load more comments button -->
                    <button id="load-more-button" data-offset="{{ batch_size }}" data-show-load-more="{{ show_all|yesno:"true,false" }}">Load more comments</button>
                  {% endif %}

                  </div>
        </div>
            
        </div>
```

Now, I believe the problem is with my JavaScript because when I submit a comment, it isn't automatically displayed on the page, but when I refresh the page, the comment shows up. Also when I submit a child comment through the admin panel it shows up after a page refresh.

To reiterate, I would like only ten comments to be displayed with a "Load more comments" button at the end which when clicked would reveal the next sets of ten comments until no more comments are left at which point the "Load more comments" button would be hidden from view.

I want all this to happen asynchronously.

Below is my JavaScript code in its entirety -

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var batch_size = 10; // Set the batch size here
  var totalComments = 0;
  var displayedComments = 0;

  // Function to load more comments
  function loadMoreComments() {
    var offset = displayedComments;
    var slug = document.getElementById("comment-form").getAttribute("data-slug");
    var loadMoreURL = `/load_more_comments/${slug}/${offset}/`;

    fetch(loadMoreURL)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        try {
          console.log("Response data:", data);
          const comments = data.comments; // Access the array of comments using data.comments
          if (comments.length > 0) {
            // Render the new comments on the page
            comments.forEach((commentData) => {
              renderCommentTree(commentData);
            });
            // Update the 'offset' attribute of the "Load more comments" button
            displayedComments += comments.length;
            // Hide the "Load more comments" button if no more comments to load
            if (displayedComments >= totalComments) {
              document.getElementById("load-more-button").style.display = "none";
            }
          } else {
            // Hide the "Load more comments" button if no more comments to load
            document.getElementById("load-more-button").style.display = "none";
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error processing data:", error);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  }

  // Show only the first batch of comments
  displayedComments = batch_size;
  console.log("Total comments:", totalComments);
  console.log("Batch size:", batch_size);

  // Function to render a new comment on the page
  function renderCommentTree(commentData) {
    console.log("Rendering comment:", commentData);
    var commentHtml = `
    <div class="comment">
    <div class="comment-header">
      <h3>${commentData.user}</h3>
      <span class="timestamp">${commentData.date_posted}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-body">
      <p>${commentData.comment}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-footer">
      <button class="comment-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-comment"></i>Reply</button>
      <button class="like-button"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i>Like</button>
      <button class="like-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>Delete</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
        <div class="child-comments">
          ${renderChildComments(commentData.replies)}
        </div>
      </div>
    `;

    var commentElement = document.createElement('div');
    commentElement.innerHTML = commentHtml;

    var childCommentsContainer = commentElement.querySelector('.child-comments');
    commentData.replies.forEach((childCommentData) => {
      var childCommentElement = renderCommentTree(childCommentData);
      childCommentsContainer.appendChild(childCommentElement);
    });

    return commentElement;
  }

  // Function to fetch comments from the server and render them on the page
  function fetchAndRenderComments() {
    var slug = document.getElementById("comment-form").getAttribute("data-slug");
    var commentListURL = `/comments/${slug}/?batch_size=${batch_size}`; // Pass the batch size as a query parameter

    console.log("Fetching comments from:", commentListURL);

    fetch(commentListURL)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        try {
          console.log("Response data:", data);
          const comments = data.comment; // Access the array of comments using data.comment
          console.log("Fetched comments array:", comments);
          // Update the total number of comments
          totalComments = comments.length; // Assuming you get the total count from the server
          console.log("Total comments:", totalComments);
          // Hide the "Load more comments" button if no more comments to load
          if (totalComments <= displayedComments) {
            document.getElementById("load-more-button").style.display = "none";
          } else {
            document.getElementById("load-more-button").style.display = "block";
          }
          // Render the fetched comments
          const commentContainer = document.getElementById("comments-section");
          console.log("Appending fetched comments to:", commentContainer);
          comments.forEach((commentData) => {
            const commentElement = renderCommentTree(commentData);
            console.log("Appending comment element:", commentElement);
            commentContainer.appendChild(commentElement); // Append to the container
          });
          displayedComments += comments.length; // Update the displayed count
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error processing data:", error);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  }

  // Fetch and render comments when the page loads
  fetchAndRenderComments();

  // Fetch and render more comments when the "Load more comments" button is clicked
  document.getElementById("load-more-button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    loadMoreComments();
  });

  // Function to submit the comment form using Fetch API
  document
    .getElementById("comment-form")
    .addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

      var commentText = document.getElementById("comment-textarea").value.trim();
      if (commentText !== "") {
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        var slug = this.getAttribute("data-slug");
        var commentSubmitURL = `/comment_submit/${slug}/`;

        fetch(commentSubmitURL, {
          method: "POST",
          body: formData,
          headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
          },
        })
          .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
            }
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((data) => {
            try {
              console.log("Comment submission response:", data);
              const commentData = data.comment; // Access the comment data using data.comment
              // Render the new comment on the page
              const commentElement = renderCommentTree(commentData);
              displayedComments += 1;
            } catch (error) {
              console.error("Error processing data:", error);
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error:", error);
          });
      }
    });

  // Function to get CSRF token from cookies
  function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== "") {
      var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
      for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === name + "=") {
          cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return cookieValue;
  }
});
```

Also these are the errors on my browser console -

```
Fetched comments array: undefined
main.js:1005 
        
       Error processing data: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at main.js:987:36
main.js:1054 
        
       Error processing data: ReferenceError: renderChildComments is not defined
    at renderCommentTree (main.js:941:24)
    at main.js:1051:38
```

Here's something to note. In my browser console the Response Data shows an array, but newly added comments are only added to the array **after** a page refresh, meanwhile the "Comment Submission response" on the console displays the JSON data immediately the comment is submitted, also the "Rendering comment" on the console shows the submitted comment on the console immediately it is submitted.

And yes, I added print statements to my Python code and my server is returning the right JSON data in its proper format so I don't know why the data is showing "undefined" in my browser console. Once again, I believe it's a problem with my JavaScript.

Comment: The main thing here is whether your network tab shows the JSON response as you expect. Is that correct? Does the data structure cater for the design, in terms of comments being able to have a parent?

Comment: If you are certain that the JSON is OK then you are probably right, it is the JS. You have a lot of `console.log()` calls in your code, which is the right thing to do - how far did you get with your debugging?